# Ignore querystring value when posting form values to Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, parameter-passing, model-binding

I have a "search" form with fields and a submit button. The returned results are displayed along with a pager control which renders anchor elements.

So for example my form would have fields `company` and `product`

And I'd have an Action method something like

```
public ActionResult Index(string company, string product, int? page)
{
    var model = GetModel(company, product, page ?? 1);
    return View(model);
}
```

and the view will show the results and generate paging links like for example...

```
<a href="/?company=Microsoft&product=Windows&page=2">2</a>
```

So basically the pager re-submits the same query but with a page parameter.

The problem I'm having is that if I go to page 2 using the pager control and then submit a new search query, the page Action parameter will get mapped to the page querystring parameter from the previous paging action, whereas I need it reset to null. Otherwise I can end up on page 2 of a query results list which only has one page.

How do I fix this?

And a related question, is there any way to submit the pager parameter information without putting it in the querystring? I can't use javascript unfortunately. I don't think this is possible but thought I'd check.

Comment: @gram what specifically do you need to see in the view? Can't post the full view but I will try to provide more details if something is not clear.